Unique number to every section in "partition by"
My table:
"letter"    "time"
"a" "2024-08-14 16:57:56.563112"
"b" "2024-08-14 17:57:56.563112"
"b" "2024-08-14 18:57:56.563112"
"b" "2024-08-14 19:57:56.563112"
"a" "2024-08-14 20:57:56.563112"
"a" "2024-08-14 21:57:56.563112"
"b" "2024-08-14 22:57:56.563112"
"b" "2024-08-14 23:57:56.563112"

I want to assign unique number to each section based on letter like this:
"letter"    "time"  "section_number"
"a" "2024-08-14 16:57:56.563112"    0
"b" "2024-08-14 17:57:56.563112"    1
"b" "2024-08-14 18:57:56.563112"    1
"b" "2024-08-14 19:57:56.563112"    1
"a" "2024-08-14 20:57:56.563112"    2
"a" "2024-08-14 21:57:56.563112"    2
"b" "2024-08-14 22:57:56.563112"    3
"b" "2024-08-14 23:57:56.563112"    3

the closest I get (fond here sql group by only rows which are in sequence)
SELECT 
    letter
    ,time
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY  time)
    - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by letter ORDER BY  time) as section_number
    FROM test;

but it has duplicates (number 3)
"letter"    "time"  "section_number"
"a" "2024-08-14 16:57:56.563112"    0
"b" "2024-08-14 17:57:56.563112"    1
"b" "2024-08-14 18:57:56.563112"    1
"b" "2024-08-14 19:57:56.563112"    1
"a" "2024-08-14 20:57:56.563112"    3
"a" "2024-08-14 21:57:56.563112"    3
"b" "2024-08-14 22:57:56.563112"    3
"b" "2024-08-14 23:57:56.563112"    3


The below query will solve the issue :
Select letter, time, (SUM(tagletter) OVER (ORDER BY time ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING))-1 as section_number
from 
(Select  *,
   CASE 
        WHEN letter = LAG(letter, 1) OVER (ORDER BY time ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) THEN 0
        ELSE 1
   END as tagletter 
from your_table)

It will take both letter and time into consideration. The result is likely-


Close, you just need to subtract 1 from section_number, to start with 0. Still upvoted.

@jarlh you are very generous I would like you in my corner...

@DerekRoberts, don't worry, your answer too got an upvote.

modified to start counting from 0.

ORDER BY time ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING would be wise, in case of duplicate time values.

Thanks a lot. This was very crucial and added it in the solution.

May be ORDER BY time, letter ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING is more deterministic.

use dense_rank, if its available in you db
SELECT
    *
    ,dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY letter) -1 section_number
FROM test 


This doesn't take time into consideration. This means only section number 0 (for a) and 1 (for b) will be returned.

You are almost there, you can use CumulativeSections
here is a code snippet to guide you
I have also shown the output on here : dbfibble
WITH SectionGroups AS (
    SELECT
        letter,
        time,
        LAG(letter) OVER(ORDER BY time) AS prev_letter,
        CASE 
            WHEN LAG(letter) OVER(ORDER BY time) = letter THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
        END AS is_new_section
    FROM test
),
CumulativeSections AS (
    SELECT
        letter,
        time,
        SUM(is_new_section) OVER(ORDER BY time) - 1 AS section_number
    FROM SectionGroups
)
SELECT
    letter,
    time,
    section_number
FROM CumulativeSections
ORDER BY time;

Output desired:
letter  time              section_number
a   2024-08-14 16:57:56.563112  0
b   2024-08-14 17:57:56.563112  1
b   2024-08-14 18:57:56.563112  1
b   2024-08-14 19:57:56.563112  1
a   2024-08-14 20:57:56.563112  2
a   2024-08-14 21:57:56.563112  2
b   2024-08-14 22:57:56.563112  3
b   2024-08-14 23:57:56.563112  3


